# email account validation through a activation link

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation, email

I am trying to validate a mail account by sending a activation link to the given mail id.
For that i am generating a random number and storing it as check_activation in database.
No the problem is, no matter what id i pass in the link, the database gets updated.

Part of my codes are;

validation page:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];    

include "connect.php";  

$query = "select * from data_main where username = \"$username\"";    

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());    

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);    

$id_string = $row['check_activation'];    

$query = "update data_main set check_activation = 'validated' where  check_activation = \"$id_string\" ";    

$retrn = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());    

if($retrn !== true)    

{

        echo "error in validation".mysql_error();    
        exit;    
}
```

this is the activation link i am sending to the user.

```
$mail_body.="http://$servr/dir_name/checkactivation.php?check_activation=$textstr";
```

is there any other method i can use to validate a email account. the account should be activated only after the user click the given link and validate it.

Comment: so, validation page is called when you click on link ?

Comment: You need to get check activation string from $_GET not from database.
Customer can be log out, but he have to validate his account.

Comment: you must check, if `$_GET['check_activation'] == your database check_activation string` and if they are the same, you can update your DB and mark user's account as activated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
include      "connect.php";
$username  = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_string = $_GET['check_activation'];
$query     = "select * from data_main where username = '{$username}' AND check_activation = '{$id_string}'";    
$result    = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());    
$rows      = mysql_num_rows($result);
$retrn     = false;    

if($rows == 1)
{
    $query     = "update data_main set check_activation = 'validated' where  check_activation = '{$id_string}' ";    
    $retrn     = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "error in validation".mysql_error();    
    exit;    
}
```

#### NOTE:

You should use **[MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** to do you DBConnection